# Validating string input using while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm having a terribly tough time with this simple code. My while conditions are always ignored and the print statement is executed. Please help.

```
package Checkpoints;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Check05 {
    public static void main (String[]args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        /**
         * Write an input validation that asks the user to enter 'Y', 'y', 'N', or 'n'.
         */


        String input, Y = null, N = null;

        System.out.println("Please enter the letter 'Y' or 'N'.");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();


        while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase(Y) || !(input.equals(N)))
                //|| input !=y || input !=N ||input !=n)

            {
            System.out.println("This isn't a valid entry. Please enter the letters Y or N" );
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: You are never assigning values to Y or N, and then using them in a compare.

Comment: Your `Y` and `N` are null objects. Nothing is equal to a `null` object.

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Change this;

```
String input, Y = null, N = null;
```

to this;

```
String input, Y = "Y", N = "N";
```

So that you can compare the user input string with "Y" and "N" strings.

And this;

```
while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase(Y) || !(input.equals(N)))
```

to this;

```
while (!(input.equalsIgnoreCase(Y) || input.equalsIgnoreCase(N)))
```

because your design of condition is misaimed, as @talex warned.

Comment: Also `!input.equalsIgnoreCase(Y) || !(input.equals(N))` is wrong. It should be `!(input.equalsIgnoreCase(Y) || input.equalsIgnoreCase(N))`.

Comment: @talex Correct. Thank for the heads up pal.

Comment: If you add it to your question it become complete, but useless because question must be deleted as off-topic anyway,

Comment: Added the new condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the input to `null` since you forgot to define the values of the string `Y` and `N`.

You can define the answer values in constants like so:

```
public static final String YES = "y";
public static final String NO  = "n";

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard;
    String  input;

    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the letter 'Y' or 'N'.");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();

    while (!(input.equalsIgnoreCase(YES) || input.equalsIgnoreCase(NO))) {
        System.out.println("This isn't a valid entry. Please enter the letters Y or N" );
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
}
```

EDIT: corrected the while condition as suggested by talex

Answer (score 0):

Add this extra conditions before "while" loop to avoid this

```
    if(Y!= null && !Y.isEmpty()) 
    if(N!= null && !N.isEmpty())
```